# In clojure, how to find all the maps in a nested map that have some key

Tags: dictionary, filter, clojure

Let `m` be a nested map. 
How to find all the maps in `m` that have a some key.

For instance:

```
(def m {:a {:id 5}
        :d {:id 58}
        :x {:id 4 :c {:id 3 :d 4}}})

(recursive-filter m :id)

;; expected result: 
> ({:id 5} {:id 58} {:id 4 :c {:id 3 :d 4}} {:id 3})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With inspiration from @Symfrog:

```
(defn recursive-filter [m k]
  (filter #(and (map? %) (contains? % k)) (tree-seq map? vals m)))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following:

```
(def data {:a {:id 5}
           :d {:id 58}
           :x {:id 4 :c {:id 3 :d 4}}})

(defn recursive-filter [m f]
  (filter #(and (map? %) (f %))
          (tree-seq map? vals m)))

(recursive-filter data :id)
```

Comment: +1: good use of `tree-seq`. +1: `f` can be *any* function which performs a test on a map, not just a keyword. Cool! -1: doesn't work for keys which are not callable. -1: doesn't work if a key is mapped to the values `false` or `nil`. Net = 0

Comment: @AlexD The following can be used if a key that is not a keyword (e.g. true) needs to be used `(recursive-filter data #(get % true))`

Comment: Let me take back the "Net = 0"... this definitely deserves a +1.

Comment: Note that `#(get % true)` still doesn't work if the key is mapped to `false` or `nil`.

Comment: @AlexD In those scenarios `(recursive-filter data #(contains? % nil))` could be used, for example.